# Problem update in console

Tags: command-line, upgrade, updates

At the time of executing the command `sudo apt-get update` I get this error in the console. I have done several things to solve it, but I still have this problem.

Does anyone know what this is and how to solve it?

[image: terminal error]

Comment: You have provided a picture of text which (a) is harder to read and more importantly (b) I can't copy & paste from to look at what your problems are. I would suggest copy/pasting your url's from the error messages into a browser, and you'll likely see the issue (what is wrong,.  is bionic supported by the ppa? is it 'stable' etc). Please provide text, and not pictures of text.

Answer (score 0):

The first error on line 10, is because the url (linex.teamviewer.com) is not in use anymore.
The second error is due to a change in how the repositories are configured and the update program is not able to do the update. It is likely that the program needing to be updated is no longer being supported, and the repository is not updated properly.

Comment: then what could I do to solve it

Comment: It would probably be best to delete the programs that are not updating and replace them with another program if needed.